# Como acessar o menu item de um menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Gostaria de saber como se faz para acessar um item de um menu, para conecta-lo com uma função ou *handler*. Por exemplo, gostaria de controlar o comportamento da aplicação quando eu faço *click* no menu item.

A função `bind` pode ser útil, mas se não sei como acessar ao menu item.

Comment: Tá um pouco tarde para perguntar mas... o código que postei funcionou?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`Menu.add_command`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add_command-method) para vincular uma função a um item do [`Menu`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *

def foo():
    print ("Foo bar")

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)

menubar.add_command(label = "Foo!", command = foo)
menubar.add_command(label = "Exit", command = root.quit)

root.config(menu = menubar)
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá, obrigado pela ajuda, querendo, apenas dizer que fiz o seguinte:

```
def M_sg():
messagebox.showinfo('Msg', 'Dados')
```

e, embaixo, escrevi o chamamento da função `M_sg()`

```
menubar.add_command(label = "Mensagem", command = root.M_sg)
```